# Overwrite An Excel File through RDCOMClient Package in R

Tags: r, excel, vba, rdcomclient

I am trying to manipulate an Excel file (.xls) in R through RDCOMClient Package.

I created an Excel object in R, opened a workbook saved as .xls file format, and tried to convert the file format into .xlsx without pop-up dialog box when there is an Excel file with the same file name. Codes as below.

```
excel <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
wb    <- excel$Workbooks()$Open(Filename = "filepath.xls",Password = "xxxxx")

excel$DisplayAlerts(FALSE)

wb$SaveAs(Filename = "filepath.xlsx" ,FileFormat = 51,Password = "")
```

I got an error message when I executed the code:

```
excel$DisplayAlerts(FALSE)
```

> <'checkErrorInfo'> 8002000E  Error: invalid number of parameter.

Comment: Check this out https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/225841.html ... excel[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

Comment: Hey, @chinsoon12, thank you for the resolution, it worked !!
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it with the following:

```
excel[["DisplayAlerts"]]=FALSE
```